# What is the difference between CPU architectures?

Tags: cpu, cpu-architecture

I am always wondering what it means when on the downloads section of a website they have links like: amd64, x86, arm and ia64. I was wondering if anyone had a **simple** answer that can highlight the major architectures and how they are different. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

x86 is an instruction set created by Intel for their 8086 processors (hence the name x86). amd64 is the 64-bit version of x86 which can support higher amounts of memory created by AMD (but also supported by Intel CPUs). ARM is mainly used for mobile devices because of its low profile and energy efficiency. IA64 is the Itanium architecture also made by Intel for their server CPUs in the 2000s (It's pretty much gone now).

x86 can also be confused with IA-32 which is the 32-bit implementation of x86 (the original was 16-bit).